# Clearing the Screen in Python Shell

Tags: python, shell

I am a little confused about this program and how to clear the screen

Comment: How is your function being called in the script? Every time you run the function it builds the wordlist anew, chooses 5, and returns that list. Are you re-running the function in a loop or something?  We need a [mcve] to better understand your issue

Comment: `wordsToGuess = random.choices(wordList, 5)` would give you all 5 at once. If you get the same words over multiple starts, you got a random.seed(...) somewhere in your code that initializes the random module to the same state on each run. Your code does not replicate your error... please complete it

Comment: @G.Anderson Also calling `wordList.remove(random.choice(wordList)) is removing a random word, not the word you appended in the `wordsToGuess` list.

Comment: @Filip while that is a _very_ valid point, the way this function is designed it doesn't matter anyway, as it rebuilds the whole list each run and doesn't remember anything form previous runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wordList.remove(random.choice(wordList))` -> I assume this line is meant to remove the word that was chosen at random from the line above it so it is not repeated, but really you are just telling the program to remove a random element from the list, independent of the one that was previously chosen.

```
word = random.choice(wordList)
wordsToGuess.append(word)
wordList.remove(word)
```

Comment: `pop` might also be a good recommendation here instead of `append` and `remove`

Answer (score 2):

When executing this code:

```
wordsToGuess.append(random.choice(wordList))
wordList.remove(random.choice(wordList))
```

what you're doing is adding a random word to wordsToGuess and removing another random word (different from the first one) from your list.

The simplest solution to your problem is to use `random.sample(population,k)` to select elements from your list without replacement. You can take a look at the documentation for it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

Now it looks like this:

```
def easy():
    wordList = ["dog", "house", "food", "ice", "rich", "school", "team", "walk", "mice", "car", "airplane", "internet", "big", "red",
            "snow","wow", "lose", "run", "line", "duck", "bike", "land", "hill", "bad", "simple", "clock", "virus", "game", "sign", "end"]
    print()
    print("Okay! Welcome to the easiest mode.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You will be given five words and must try to remember them in order:")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Ready")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Set")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("REMEMBER!")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    wordsToGuess = random.sample(wordList, 5)
    print(wordsToGuess)
    time.sleep(4)
    print(("\n") * 100)
    print("Let's see how good your memory really is")
    return wordsToGuess
```

Answer (score 1):

This will "flash" the values on the screen and not print them all together in a list.
I also added a 1/2 second delay between the prints to look better.

```py
import time
import random

def easy():
    word_list = ["dog", "house", "food", "ice", "rich", "school", "team", "walk", "mice", "car", "airplane", "internet", "big", "red",
                 "snow","wow", "lose", "run", "line", "duck", "bike", "land", "hill", "bad", "simple", "clock", "virus", "game", "sign", "end"]
    print()
    print("Okay! Welcome to the easiest mode.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You will be given five words and must try to remember them in order:")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Ready")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Set")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("REMEMBER!")
    time.sleep(0.5)

    words_to_guess = []
    for i in range(5):
        word = random.choice(word_list)
        words_to_guess.append(word)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        word_list.remove(word)
        print(words_to_guess[i])
    time.sleep(4)
    print(("\n") * 100)
    print("Let's see how good your memory really is")

    return words_to_guess
```

I didn't see the rest of the code though. i am guessing `easy` is the gamemode, but why end it so fast? You could maybe instead of returning the `words_to_guess` list, have the user input words and give him some time to type, probably in a thread or something.

Not an answer, more like a suggestion:

```py
import time
import random
import threading

def counter(time):
    time.sleep(time)

def get_input(words: int, time: float):
    word_list = []
    print("You will have {} seconds to write all the words you remember!".format(time))
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Start!")
    countdown = threading.Thread(target=counter, args=time)
    countdown.start()

    while countdown.isAlive():
        if words > 0:
            word = input("Write the words!\n")
            word_list.append(word)
            words -= 1
        else:
            break
    return word_list


def easy():
    word_list = ["dog", "house", "food", "ice", "rich", "school", "team", "walk", "mice", "car", "airplane", "internet", "big", "red",
                 "snow","wow", "lose", "run", "line", "duck", "bike", "land", "hill", "bad", "simple", "clock", "virus", "game", "sign", "end"]
    print()
    print("Okay! Welcome to the easiest mode.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You will be given five words and must try to remember them in order:")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Ready")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Set")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("REMEMBER!")
    time.sleep(0.5)

    words_to_guess = []
    for i in range(5):
        word = random.choice(word_list)
        words_to_guess.append(word)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        word_list.remove(word)
        print(words_to_guess[i])
    time.sleep(4)
    print(("\n") * 100)
    print("Let's see how good your memory really is")

    words = get_input(5, 10)  # this will give the user 10 seconds to write 5 words
    wrongs = []
    for i in range(words):
        if words[i] != words_to_guess[i]:
            wrongs.append(i)
    if wrongs:
        print("You made {} mistakes:\n".format(len(wrongs)))
        for i in range(wrongs):
            print("{}) You wrote '{}'. The word was ''".format(i, wrongs[i], words_to_guess[i]))
    else:
        print("Nice! You made no mistakes!")
```

I didn't run it, but it might work :P

By the way the *best practice* in python is to use snake case (**snake_case**) for `variable` names and `function` names. You can use camel case (**camelCase**) but only for `class` names

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using this function in a loop or something that repeats the function, if you are then you need to move the list out of function. because every time you call it, it makes the same list over and over.